# How to get which dependency and dependency version will pack into war file in gradle build file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to print all dependency groupId, artifactId and version which will pack into war package in multiple module gradle project.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the [`dependencies` task](https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#sec:listing_dependencies) on the project that defines the `war`. And in the linked documentation page has a number of other methods for investigating dependencies of a Gradle project.